# Solr does not find substring

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot

I have a rails 4 application running sunspot solr with the following filters in the schema.xml

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have a city named "Alpe d'Huez" which I wan't to be found by solr.
Solr only finds this record as long as you start typing Alpe, but I want it to be found by just typing in "huez"
How can this be achieved? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below configuration and if search term contains special characters then enter search term within double quotes.

```
<fieldType name="search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="150">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: this config works great! Thank you so much. Could you explain what makes the difference and why not using EdgeNGramFilterFactory ?

Comment: EdgeNGramFilterFactory creates n-grams from starting point of token while NGTF creates n-tokens from both ends.<br>
e.g. n-grams comparison for both factories-<br>
      token- hello<br>
      EedgeNGFF: h, he, hel, hell, hello<br>
      NGFF: h,he,hel,hell,hello,hellow,e,el,ell,ello,ellow,l,ll,llo,llow,l,lo,low,o

Answer (score 1):

Right off, your analysis looks a bit questionable.

First, it's most typical for your query and index analyzers to be identical, or nearly so (this isn't a hard and fast rule, but if they diverge you should know *why*).  If they are too different, the query terms won't match up well with the indexed terms, and you'll often get no results.

Using both `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` *and* `NGramFilterFactory` is pretty odd.  Essentially, you split the tokens into ngrams, and split out ngrams from your ngrams.  This doesn't strike me as particularly useful, unless you are really intending to take the shotgun blast approach to searching.

You are applying a stemmer (`PorterStemFilterFactory`) in your query time analysis, but not at index time.  You're stemmer should be applied at both times for it to be useful.

Further, NGrams and Stemmers don't really play well together.  If you need to use both, you should probably index them in different fields.

And minor point on `TrimFilterFactory`: it doesn't actually do anything here.  You're using `StandardTokenizer`, so input is already being split on whitespace.  `TrimFilterFactory` is rarely useful on anything but keyword analyzed fields.

If you aren't sure how you need to analyze, it might be most useful to just start with standard analysis :

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index" class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
  <analyzer type="query" class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
</fieldType>
```

And go from there.

Otherwise, something like this might be the closest to what you've provided that seems pretty reasonable:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```